# Check values greater than int with condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I have this dataframe:

`t = pd.DataFrame(data={"Pos": [1, 2, 3], "A": [10, 2, 90], "B":[90, 98, 10]})`

I would like to know which of the **(values in A and B >= 20) but only if (Pos = 1 or 3)**.

The result should look like this:

```
"A"     "B"
False   True
True    True
True    False
```

I can find the values >= 20 using `t[["A", "B"]].ge(20)` but I cannot seem to find a way to add the condition based on Pos.

Would a kind soul be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask:

```
t[['A', 'B']].ge(20).where(t['Pos'].isin([1, 3]), True)
```

Alternative with [`numpy.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) and boolean inversion `~`:

```
np.logical_or(t[["A", "B"]].ge(20), ~t['Pos'].isin([1, 3]).values[:,None])
```

output:

```
       A      B
0  False   True
1   True   True
2   True  False
```